# How to set up a wi-fi hotspot with an Ubuntu laptop (access point mode)?

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point, hot-spot

I've read [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode), and carefully followed the instructions provided. I am sure the wireless card in my laptop supports going into wireless access point mode.
But unfortunately, when I use the following command to start `hostapd` service it throws an error:

```
 $ sudo service hostapd stop
 Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management hostapd                      [fail]
```

The instructions mentioned above said this could possibly be because my wireless card does not support the g mode, and provided the wiki of `hostapd`.
But what is g mode? I tried to switch to a, or b mode, but it just didn't work.

Can anyone help with this or recommend a tool like connectify in windows ?

ps. I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit. I have an ADSL wired network, and I want to share it by setting my laptop into a WiFi hotspot with  my windows phone.

Comment: I have tried the ap-hotspot in my ubuntu 12.04 , but getting the authentication problem while connecting the devices on Wifi with the hotspot.

Comment: @skumar ap-hotspot is dreprecated. Try [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since **ap-hotspot** is **deprecated**, it's neither reliable or stable for newer Ubuntu distribution. The author of **ap-hotspot** recommended **[create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)**.

### Installation

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

### Usage

#### No passphrase (open network):

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint
```

#### WPA + WPA2 passphrase:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Change `wlan0` and `eth0` to the interface on your machine. (`ifconfig`)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, and this worked the best for me.

Answer (score 11):

You need to create infrastructure (Access Point mode) wireless hot-spot rather Ad-hoc hot-spot.
In linux(ubuntu) i used **ap-hotspot** and which works for me(i got connected WP8 and Android 4.4, dont know about iPhones).

#### For installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

#### Update for 14.04

The hostapd version in Ubuntu 14.04 is buggy and doesn't work properly. To get AP-Hotspot to work with hostapd in Ubuntu 14.04, you need to downgrade hostapd and use apt to hold the package so it's not upgraded.

To do this, use the following commands:
**For 32 Bit:**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

**For 64 Bit**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

#### Configuration

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

[image: Configure_Sample]

It will asks for interfaces, Access point name(which can be anything you want to see as wifi_hotspot name), password(which is your wifi_hotspot security key).

Now, if you able to configure successfully and dont get any kind of Unsupported wifi errors(if you get that simply means, your wifi_card doesnt support infrastrucutre Access point wifi_hotspot, so can do nothing on it), then procceed.

So just now start your hotspot as

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

If you want to stop then

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

If you wanna see all available commands

```
sudo ap-hotspot
```

You don't see this hot-spot running in any indicator or something, i am still finding it how to determine status checking of it.

I am using is from last few weeks, and no bugs(no side-effects too) yet. I am using Gnome-Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 sharing eth0 to my WP8.

SOURCE : http://www.unixmen.com/create-infrastructure-wifi-access-point-connect-android-devices/
SOURCE : http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html

Comment: NOTE for 14.04.

Comment: You must read the second source link if you are using Ubuntu14.04.

Comment: I have installed the ap-hotspot and when i tried to configure it it's giving me this error *Your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode* what should i do now for creating hotspot

Comment: @Eka ap-hotspot is dreprecated. Try [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

Answer (score 7):

I have 2 wi-fi adapters installed for this. One native internal, and other via USB. I have to share with external USB because the internal one I am using to receive my conection. In your case you don't need another adapter, as you receive the conection via cable. Just follow my steps.
This is how I do. In `System Settings...`>`Networks` select the Wi-Fi adapter you want to uuse as a Hotspon, and click <kbd>Use as Hotspot...</kbd> button.

[image]

This will shortly activate the adapter to serve as a **Hotspot**.
At the same window you have <kbd>Options...</kbd> function, and you can stop it in a same easy way.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried that method before. But it seems that it's ad-hoc mode, not AP. I am not sure my windows phone can get access to it.
And when I "use as hotspot", the connection disconnected as soon as it connected sucessfully.

Comment: I tried the same thing on Ubuntu 12.04 but it does not seem to work. What shall I do to figure out the problem?

Comment: I guess it cannot work with `.local` domain. As you will need to have another domain account for each device you want to connect. Did you try to debug [from here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)?