# How to install apps for windows phone in Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

I have a Nokia Lumia with Windows Phone operating system. But software like Zune can't run in Ubuntu(Neither with wine), and I have no WiFi network. I am trying to set my laptop into a WiFi hotspot with a wired network, and put up [this  qurestion.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323335/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-an-ubuntu-laptop-access-point-mode) 
So how can I install apps for my windows phone with an Ubuntu laptop ?

Can anyone help ? Thanks!

Comment: Zune works under WinE on Ubuntu. This question should be asked from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to directly install the Zune program in ubuntu so 
You can first install Zune in windows, after that boot linux and try to add zune with WinE or add .exe file in WinE now it may be work.