# How to share ubuntu laptop ethernet to android 4.2.2 via usb?

Tags: 12.04, internet

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 laptop and 4.2.2 android phone. My phone cannot show ad-hoc network from my Ubuntu sharing network. So now I try to connect internet via USB from computer.

I've seen this solution for Windows only, is there one for Ubuntu?

Comment: [This thread from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1212548) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I also want an answer for this question about how to share PC internet via USB and searched on various forums, but get only one answer: "You can share your PC Internet with other device via creating a WI-FI hotspot"

Please go through these reference links:

- [How to set up a wi-fi hotspot with an Ubuntu laptop (access point mode)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323335/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-an-ubuntu-laptop-access-point-mode)
- [Create WiFi hotspot on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)
- [How to create a WiFi hotspot for Android/Windows in Ubuntu](http://technobytz.com/wifi-hotspot-android-windows-ubuntu.html)
- [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-connect-share-your-internet-connection-wired-wireless)