# how to create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I want to create a wifi hotspot in Ubuntu like connectify creates hotspot in windows...where i can use internet on my laptop as well as mobile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/318973/263726)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create WiFi hotspot on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go in System Settings > Network and then in the Wireless section, click on "Use as hotspot".

After the security notification, it will show you the network name and the wep key needed to connect to this network (those informations can be customized).

For more details, you can also check : http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point