# is there any way to create a hidden hotspot from ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I would like to create a hidden hotspot from my Ubuntu for my phone, is there any way to do this? I want that only people who know the SSID can connect to the WiFi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create WiFi hotspot on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Have you read HIDDEN??????

Comment: Why? Further reading: http://superuser.com/questions/167452/how-to-make-my-wifi-connection-hidden

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way known to create the access Point hotspot with hidden SSID. However to do Wifi hotspot without hidden SSID:

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

With screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with this script https://github.com/Daniyal-Javani/AP-Hotspot

You can run this with downloading ap-hotspot file and do `chmod 777 ap-hotspot` or install with `sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot` Then change codes in `/usr/bin/ap-hotspot` with my script!

Answer (score 1):

I needed exactly this, and didn't find a solution else where. Posting for when my future self inevitably forgets it.

NetworkManager now [allows hidden SSID in AP mode](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/merge_requests/17).

After creating the hotspot, edit the generated connection file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot.nmconnection` and add `hidden=true` under `[wifi]`, it should look something like

```
[wifi]
hidden=true
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
```

Then reload and restart the connection:

```
sudo nmcli connection reload Hotspot
nmcli connection up Hotspot
```