# How do I create a hidden WiFi hotspot without a password?

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to make a hotspot that is hidden and without a password.

I created the hotspot with the Network-Manager GUI, then I went to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` and added the `hidden=true` part to the file acording to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1376205).

Now this is my file:

```
-----------------------------------
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=66cb275f-8c03-41b1-ad69-8992b21ff655
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlx90f6520ed959

[wifi]
mode=ap
ssid=betagaming
hidden=true

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=qnFYm2Db

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]
```

What do I have to change so that the hotspot does not have a password?

Comment: im guessing its in this part [wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=qnFYm2Db

Comment: iknow they are not secure i just want to do  a hiden wifi with no password

Comment: No, I don't think you can use WPA without a password. You'll probably need to set the network up without any encryption, which also means that anyone in range can intercept unencrypted traffic between devices.

Comment: Yep. @Nmath is correct: No password (or pre-shared key), no encryption.