# ICS over existing WiFi network

Tags: connection-sharing

I have an existing WiFi network which all my devices are connected to. I had a falling out with my dad, and he set up a blocker on the WiFI stopping my phone and tablet connecting to the internet through WiFi, but my Ubuntu laptop still has internet access.

I need to set up my laptop as a gateway for my phone and tablet (phone is running Cyanogenmod 12 and tablet is on Android 5.0.2 if it's important) to connect to, so my other devices can use its internet.

Comment: Use your Ubuntu laptop as a portable hotspot. Follow the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I cannot use the laptop as a portable hotspot as its connection exists over wifi and to use as a hotspot would require wlan0 to be used as a hotspot instead of a receiver.

Comment: This is outside the scope of AU, but since you have a rooted phone, you could try using Chainfire's *Pry-Fi* (look it up on the Play Store) to spoof your MAC address. Note that this uses up a lot of battery in the process.

Answer (score 0):

As you need your WiFi card to connect to the Internet, and you have no wired capabilities, you basically have 3 possibilities:  **Two are technical and one is not.**

1. Buy an additional WiFi USB dongle that is Linux compatible and has AP (=Access Point) capabilities.  Be careful to mention both capabilities when you buy the card so that you can return it if it's not.
   Set the dongle up as an [access point](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu) and have both your phone and tablet connect to it.
2. If dad has been smart, he has whitelisted your laptop and this trick will not work.  If not, he has *blacklisted* both your phone and tablet.  You just have to go to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questios/ask) and ask "How to allow MAC address spoofing on my xxx" where xxx is the type / model / OS of your phone and tablet.
3. Instead of looking for ways around your punishment, you should accept your fate, be nice to dad and ensure this doesn't happen again!  Start by printing off this Q&A, go to dad and say "I'm sorry!"

## ;-)