# Can't connect to own Ubuntu-created WiFi hotspot

Tags: wireless, 15.04, intel-wireless, ap-hotspot

I followed this guide to create a hotspot:

[Create WiFi hotspot on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)

I go through all the steps but when it comes to the end, connecting my laptop to the hotspot, it does not work.

I have tried connecting to a hidden WiFi network but this also does not connect.

Can anyone help?

```
$ lsb_release -a
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
    Release:    15.04
    Codename:   vivid

$ uname -a
Linux mylinux 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ sudo cat android-wifi 
[connection]
id=android-wifi
uuid=af9a2d23-c1e4-409d-a80e-d8c8271ba291
type=wifi

[wifi]
ssid=android-wifi
mode=ap
mac-address=A0:A8:CD:6F:0C:34

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk-flags=1

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
method=auto
ip6-privacy=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

After following the guide and before enabling WiFi, restart the Network Manager with:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Then enable WiFi and it should connect.

Comment: This does nothing. Some processes used by `network-manager` won't restart after this command.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. After restarting network manager it shows same as "Authentication problem". Any other solution ??

Answer (score 1):

I too face same problem that you had I and I solved by.
Going into system settings;  Click the Network Icon -> **Edit Connections** -> Select your Wifi Network (In your case select **android-wifi** ) -> Click **Edit**.

A dialogue box opes like this.
[image]
Make sure you have checked **Automatically connect to this Network..**.

After that **Restart** your computer.

Your Wifi Network is now available to use.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: This should not make any difference, it just tells the computer to connect to this network automatically if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following edits in  ***/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/android-wifi***
You may use `$sudo gedit android-wifi`  to edit it.

- Add a line 
  `security=wifi-security`
  after
  `mac-address=A0:A8:CD:6F:0C:34`
- Replace the line
  `psk-flags=1`
  by `psk="password wthout quotes"`
- Delete the last line.
  `ip6-privacy=0`

**Now the file should look like this**

```
[connection]
id=android-wifi
uuid=af9a2d23-c1e4-409d-a80e-d8c8271ba291
type=wifi

[wifi]
ssid=android-wifi
mode=ap
mac-address=A0:A8:CD:6F:0C:34
security=wifi-security

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk="password wthout quotes"

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

Answer (score 0):

#### BE CAREFUL WITH THE FIREWALL

First try:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

If that solves the problem, you can do:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw       allow in  on wlo1
sudo ufw route allow out on enp41s0
```

My system works with:

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
[ 1] Anywhere on wlo1           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] Anywhere on enp41s0        ALLOW FWD   Anywhere       (out)
[ 3] Anywhere (v6) on wlo1      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] Anywhere (v6) on enp41s0   ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)  (out)
```

Only `[ 1]` and `[ 2]` are strictly necessary.

#----------------------------------------------------- On my system:

With WiFi on:

```
ifconfig

> enp41s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.2.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
>         inet6 fe80::19b0:6542:ee4:5982  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 00:d8:61:9e:2b:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 46282  bytes 39478576 (39.4 MB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 38257  bytes 7380268 (7.3 MB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> enp42s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         ether 00:d8:61:9e:2b:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 1981  bytes 318831 (318.8 KB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 1981  bytes 318831 (318.8 KB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.2.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
>         inet6 fe80::1c39:c0d6:43bd:fcf0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 38:00:25:95:18:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 50  bytes 17772 (17.7 KB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 48  bytes 7067 (7.0 KB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

This means that the WiFi hotspot:
input is from wlo1
Output is to enp42s0
```