# Ubuntu 20.04 hotspot not working

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, hot-spot

I occasionally require hotspot from my laptop which runs Ubuntu 20.04 and till yesterday it was working, but without me doing anything it stopped. It shows that my Hotspot is on, it shows signals even on my phone but for some reason, I can't connect to it. I use wired connection for my laptop. Also, I've a dual boot and hotspot is still working fine on windows.

I ve referred a few solutions including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726660/cant-connect-to-own-ubuntu-created-wifi-hotspot), but nothing works for me.

I don't know what output would help in solving this question, I'm just posting output of lshw -c network

> *-network
> description: Wireless interface
> product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
> logical name: wlp4s0
> version: 1a
> serial: 8c:c6:81:f0:2f:67
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
> configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi            driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
> resources: irq:71 memory:fea00000-fea03fff
> *-network
> description: Ethernet interface
> product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
> vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
> logical name: enp5s0
> version: 15
> serial: 2c:f0:5d:66:42:09
> size: 1Gbit/s
> capacity: 1Gbit/s
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
> configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.103.136 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
> resources: irq:52 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff

Comment: It looks like your wifi card is already connected to a network, as it has address 192.168.0.105, which probably is not a hotspot-created IP address. Disconnect, and then retry hotspot.

Comment: @heynnema, it seems I was connected to my friend's wifi at the time of running that command. Anyways I ran it again this time with hotspot on, got ip=10.42.0.1 . The same problem as I said earlier

Comment: I was tired of attempting to fix stuff, so i just reinstalled ubuntu, this time 21.04 and everything seems fine for now

Comment: except it isn't fine now :( , without me doing anything the same problem came in 21.04.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i wlp4s0 /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*`. If the output is large, paste it at https://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @heynnema , I've added the output of those commands https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7kF6JCrngj/

Comment: Thanks for the syslog data. I don't really see anything that catches my eye there. Try this... from the GRUB menu, try booting to an older kernel. I want to eliminate a problem with kernel 5.11.0-27-generic. Report back.

Comment: I tried with kernel 5.10.0-051000-generic, the problem persists

Comment: Now try and boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if hotspot works. If it does work, then there is some software problem in your system. Just trying to eliminate some possible problem areas with my questions. Report back.

Comment: do netstat -n to see if port 67 or 53 are in use.
NetworkManager requests an IP address for the Wifi interface as it sets it up. It probably starts & uses an internal dhcp server but if it fails to get an IP it still creates the connection but the connection has no IP so when you connect to it it cannot supply the IP/DNS/Gateway to the new connection.(it can't talk to a dhcp server because it has no IP/gateway for itself).
Still looking for a solution for a similar problem type.