# Created hotspot in ubuntu 16.04 is not able to connect

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I had created hotspot using kde-nm-connection-manager in ubuntu 15.10 and was able to connect to it successfully. When I tried to do it in ubuntu 16.04 after upgrading, it says failed to activate connection, under which it reads "(2) Connection 'Hotspot' is not available on the device wlo1 at this time."

I have also tried methods suggested in [how to creat wifi hotspot in ubuntu 16.04 since AP-Hotspot is no more working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762846/how-to-creat-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-16-04-since-ap-hotspot-is-no-more-working), but they also did not work. Please help.

Comment: why dont I get any response.

Answer (score 3):

This problem may occur because the driver of your wi-fi card does not support the AP (Access Point) mode. Because your WAN interface name is "wlo1" I assume you use Broadcom proprietary driver "wl", which does not support the AP mode.

You should use another wi-fi card driver with AP mode support to avoid this error.

Answer (score 2):

For example, I use "b43" driver for my BCM4312 LP-PHY card instead the default "wl" driver.

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43

How to install it:

1. Connect your PC/laptop to the router via Ethernet cable and disable your wi-fi connection in the Network manager.
2. Go to Settings - Software & updates - Additional driver bookmark - BCM4312 -> Do not use the device - Apply changes.
3. sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
4. sudo reboot
5. Enable the wi-fi connection in the Network manager.

See here for details:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395)