# ubuntu 16.04 hotspot. Client has no internet

Tags: networking, internet, android

I created hotspot using this solution [How to create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu 16.04 since AP-Hotspot is no more working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762846/how-to-creat-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-16-04-since-ap-hotspot-is-no-more-working)

It works great, BUT no clients (android phone, or windows PC) have internet connection. It "see" my wifi web, smoothly connect to it, but cannot browse sites.

In win7 I`ve got a connectify and it works great! Btw, problem can be in my stupid internet provider.

Can you help me? please?

```
  ########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 08 Nov 2016 22:54 EET +0200

Booted last: 08 Nov 2016 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H121.05 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e025]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [144d:c553]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1210:25f4 DigiTech 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 143360  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:178.54.37.46  Bcast:178.54.37.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fec0::d:/64 Scope:Site
          inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2002:b236:1c20:d:/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:119213 errors:0 dropped:32 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21695347 (21.6 MB)  TX bytes:2186636 (2.1 MB)
          Interrupt:18 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5840 errors:0 dropped:20 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:571495 (571.4 KB)  TX bytes:226022 (226.0 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         178.54.37.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
178.54.37.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     100    0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search 195.69.84.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       866     1  0 22:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         sky2
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.30
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/0000:04:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     narhoz
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6f136c44-8b4a-4c24-a63a-ab7b361d9cce
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6f136c44-8b4a-4c24-a63a-ab7b361d9cce | narhoz
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         178.54.37.46/25
IP4.GATEWAY:                            178.54.37.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             194.0.91.163
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2002:b236:1c20:d:/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fec0::d:/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::91a0:19bc:ab15:23f3
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2002::/16, nh = fe80::91a0:19bc:ab15:23f3, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fec0:0:0:d::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 2002:b236:1c20:d::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (T77H121.05 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath9k
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-45-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Dima_HotSpot
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       b89fe584-be7e-44cf-97ee-eabf20a2cc3f
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   b89fe584-be7e-44cf-97ee-eabf20a2cc3f | Dima_HotSpot
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

SSID          BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE      SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Dima_HotSpot    Infra  1     2412 MHz  0 Mbit/s  0       ____  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Dima_HotSpot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Dima_HotSpot | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Dima_HotSpot
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Chisinau (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     323EDC06388A3D0920FD7FC
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     6FBD9F8A613FDFA282AB4FE
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     BF9F4930086BABAAF3CD9BA
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     3FCDBF7CE71CB8FB980D59D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     F1176862D12ECD05A1066CF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x11ab:0x4354 (sky2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x002b (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   20.947833] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   20.950270] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[   20.950273] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[   20.950275] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   20.950277] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   20.950278] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[   40.959792] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   40.980871] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   40.983514] sky2 0000:04:00.0 eth0: enabling interface
[   40.983746] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   41.803299] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   42.853125] sky2 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex, flow control rx
[   42.853152] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   42.902727] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: That question has multiple answers. What exactly did you do to reach the current state?

Comment: Everything in the manual. Nothing more.

Comment: What manual? O_o

Comment: Like I said at the top of the post. This one http://askubuntu.com/questions/762846/how-to-creat-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-16-04-since-ap-hotspot-is-no-more-working

Comment: Which post? The question, each of the answers and all their comments are all posts. Could you please either 1) link directly to the post that you mean (for answers use the link below them that reads "share", for comments use the link embedded in the the post date) or 2) [edit] your question to describe your actions.