# nmcli command not found ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, nmcli

I'm trying to create a hotspot in ubuntu so I need to disable the wifi. When tried the command `nmcli radio wifi off` it returns the message `bash: nmcli: command not found`. Is there anyway to install nmcli on ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu _Server_? I don't think it uses _Network Manager_ by default.

Comment: It's not a server, I'm running ubuntu on my chromebook.

Comment: I guess you are following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/762885) or similar answer? You could just skip the step of disabling wifi

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin/nmcli` is part of the `network-manager` package.

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ type -p nmcli
/usr/bin/nmcli
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/nmcli
network-manager: /usr/bin/nmcli
                # Read `man apt-cache`. What depends on network-manager?
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-cache rdepends network-manager
network-manager
Reverse Depends:
  nplan
  network-manager-gnome
  gce-startup-scripts
  gce-daemon
  cockpit-networkmanager
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
  ubuntu-mate-core
  ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
 |nplan
  network-manager-openconnect
  network-manager-openconnect
  libpurple0
  evolution
  connman
  resolvconf
  network-manager-gnome
  wader-core
  ubuntu-touch
  ubuntu-push-client
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
  ubuntu-mate-core
  ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  tlp-rdw
  sugar-session
  sugar-presence-service-0.88
  sugar-presence-service
 |sugar-presence-service
  python-networkmanager
  python-jarabe
  plinth
  plasma-nm
  network-manager-strongswan
 |modem-manager-gui
  ppp
  mate-gnome-main-menu-applet
  mailnag
  liferea
  libpurple0
  indicator-network-tools
  indicator-network
  gajim
  freedombox-setup
  evolution
  connman
  resolvconf
  modemmanager
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic
  network-manager-gnome
                # Read `man apt-cache`. What does network-manager depend on?
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-cache depends network-manager
network-manager
  Depends: libbluetooth3
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgnutls30
  Depends: libgudev-1.0-0
  Depends: libmm-glib0
  Depends: libndp0
  Depends: libnewt0.52
  Depends: libnl-3-200
  Depends: libnm0
  Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0
  Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  Depends: libreadline6
  Depends: libsoup2.4-1
  Depends: libsystemd0
  Depends: libuuid1
  Depends: init-system-helpers
  Depends: lsb-base
  Depends: dnsmasq-base
  Depends: wpasupplicant
    wpasupplicant:i386
  Depends: dbus
    dbus:i386
  Depends: udev
    udev:i386
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: isc-dhcp-client
  Depends: libpam-systemd
  Depends: policykit-1
    policykit-1:i386
  Conflicts: connman
  Breaks: network-manager-gnome
  Breaks: <network-manager-kde>
  Breaks: network-manager-openconnect
  Breaks: network-manager-openvpn
  Breaks: network-manager-pptp
  Breaks: network-manager-vpnc
  Breaks: <plasma-widget-networkmanagement>
  Breaks: ppp
  Recommends: ppp
  Recommends: iptables
  Recommends: modemmanager
    wader-core
  Recommends: crda
    crda:i386
  Recommends: iputils-arping
  Recommends: network-manager-pptp
 |Recommends: network-manager-gnome
 |Recommends: <plasma-widget-networkmanagement>
  Recommends: plasma-nm
  Suggests: avahi-autoipd
  Suggests: python
```

Comment: So is there any way to use nmcli?

Comment: The only way to run `nmcli` is by installing the `network-manager` package (and its dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

`nmcli` is part of `network-manager`

So one way to install it is by using this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

After installation it will find `nmcli` as a command.