# create wifi hotspot in ubuntu-14.04 when connected to another wireless network

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hot-spot

My machine ubuntu-14.04 is connected to a wireless network. The wireless network does not allow mobile devices to connect to it and access internet.

I am trying to setup my laptop as access point, so that I can connect my mobile device to the laptop and get internet access on my phone.

Is there a way I can set up a wifi hotspot in ubuntu-14.04 connected to wireless network. I know way to create when connected to ethernet lan, but how to do this with wireless network.

If anybody knows please help.

Comment: Possible if you have two wireless cards (I think, not sure though)

Comment: i have done this in windows. but not able to find also relevant result on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a second USB WIFI interface. Apparently you can use the same network card if both wireless connection are on the same channel or if the card support multiple connections.

I used this method:

[Create WiFi hotspot on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)

For ubuntu 16 it's straight forward, for ubuntu 14, you have to edit:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-hotspot
```

and write hotspot mode manually since that option it's not available in the network-manager graphical interface for ubuntu 14.