# Toggle WLAN Hotspot Gnome Taskbar

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, network-manager, wireless-access-point

I have a mobile broadband connection that I am often sharing via hotspot on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Gnome 3.28.2. I can perfectly do this (as described for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490950/create-wifi-hotspot-on-ubuntu)) via GUI. But I would like to realize that with a CLI command (for a toggle switch. How can I determine the command behind this GUI button: [image: WLAN Hotspot] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused with the example you have provided in the question.. it uses Unity..
but 18.04 Defaults to GNOME

I assume you are using GNOME and not Unity..

Once you have created the hotspot in any way and once it is active..

run the below command
`nmcli device show`

and note down the value for `GENERAL.CONNECTION:`
in my case it is `Hotspot-21`

Example:

```
pratap@i3-6550U:~$ nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E0:94:67:64:C5:8F
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Hotspot-21
```

now use the commands below to toggle on and off (#Replace `Hotspot-21` with your value)

```
nmcli connection up Hotspot-21
nmcli connection down Hotspot-21
```

[image]

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmcli.1.html

```
       wifi hotspot [ifname ifname] [con-name name] [ssid SSID] [band {a | bg}] [channel channel]
   [password password]
       Create a Wi-Fi hotspot. The command creates a hotspot connection profile according to
       Wi-Fi device capabilities and activates it on the device. The hotspot is secured with
       WPA if device/driver supports that, otherwise WEP is used. Use connection down or
       device disconnect to stop the hotspot.
```

Comment: This is brilliant, exactly what I looked for. I am facing one last problem: As showed in your video I can switch the Hotspot off. But when switching on after a while I get an error as follows (translated from german):
`Error: Link activation failed: 802.1X supplicant took too long to legitimize`
Any idea where that might come from?

Comment: no - when turning on via gui everything is ok. when i send the command `nmcli connection up Hotspot` it toggles the button stays on for a certain time and switches off again with above error...

Comment: oddly when I switch on via GUI, down via nmcli and up via nmcli again, above error occurs, when I switch on via CLI from the beginning, everything is ok. Well, case closed! Thank you again!