# UBUNTU 14.04LTS Wi-Fi hotspot is not detected by android phone

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, android, hot-spot

Default creation of HotSpot in network manager is not able to detected on andriod phones of any version.
There is a answer for this question in given link below but its need to install third party repository

[Link for an answer to this Question (but with 3rd party repository)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323335/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-an-ubuntu-laptop-access-point-mode)

How can one make the ubuntu default setting of a hotspot creation to be detected on smartphones ?

Comment: Here I have found the answer for my question and its working perfectly on my ubuntu laptop having ubuntu 14.04 LTS; even andriod phone capture the hotspot created by Ubuntu. Click on the below link for answer. **[https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734)**

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate of another as the original poster has specified that the other question answered their question.

Answer (score 8):

here is a clear guide to create a Wi-Fi hotspot detectable by any Android phone on a Ubuntu 14.04 using the Network Manager and a minor hack:

1. Click on Network manager -> Create new Wi-Fi network
2. sudo nano the newly created file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/yourWifiNetworkName
3. change the mode line to: mode=ap

Thats all! From now on you can enable this network from Network manager -> Create new Wi-Fi network -> Connection: select yourWifiNetworkName from the dropdown

source:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Comment: Hotspot is visible but device cannot connect

Comment: check syslog and fix the errors it shows when you try to connect

Answer (score 1):

**By default Android cannot connect to ad-hoc wireless networks (regardless of whether you are using Windows, Linux, Mac etc.)**

There are third party apps (as mentioned) that you can install on your Android device but they might not be compatible, have problems or require you to root your handset.

You need to find out how to turn your wireless into an **infrastructure** type network for your phone to be able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Important is the

```
 Method: shared to other computers
```

in ipv4 settings which is bridging the wifi to the existing internet connected network.
This permits the DHCP requests from the Android to succeed.

This works pretty much out of the box in ubuntu 16.04. Restarting the network manager

```
   service network-manager restart
```

might be required though

Answer (score 1):

As some people has said that default creation of hotspot is not able to get it in use with android or any other OS.

So you have to use it another way.

first go to edit connections from task bar and add new connection in WiFi section.

Remember to use security with *wpa & wpa2 personal* method.
Also in genral tab, tick option that *all users may connect to this network*.

```
ssid = any name of your choice (e.g. Myhotspot)

mode : hotspot

band : Automatic

channel: default

Device: select your wireless adapter from drop down menu.
```

Leave ipv4 and ipv6 settings. and save the setting.

Then from **taskbar** to start the hotspot,click on **create new WiFi network**
and then in *connection* select **hotspot** and click on **create**.
now you can use it in any device.

*NOTE: dont turn on hotspot from network setting (From use as hotspot)*

> This method is for Ubuntu unity desktop version