# Is it possible to run rtl8188eu in ap mode?

Tags: drivers, wireless-access-point

i can run my wifi card (rtl8188eu) in ap mode in windows by using Realtek Wireless LAN Utility or Connectify.. But When i tried in ubuntu i got an error saying..

> (32) Access Point (AP) mode is not supported by this device

How to fix this?

UPDATE: How did i try to set up an ap..

I used Network manager to create an wifi infrastructure network "**Wi-Fi connection 1**" and change the field **mode=infrastructure** to **mode=ap** in file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1.
and tried connecting to that network via connect to hidden network.

Edit: i just need to share my Wired Internet to other wifi deviecs through my wifi card.. not to connectify...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what you did to setup AP. It should support it.

Comment: @Pilot6.... edited

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

Comment: @Pilot6.. It is not... i dont need to run ap and get Internet from wifi simultaneously.. i just need to run my wifi card as ap alone.. and share my wired connection..

Comment: But still read the answer. It gives directions how to setup AP. And also I met that realtek needs a custom hostapd. Anyway you won't set it in NM.

Comment: Also read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/323335/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-an-ubuntu-laptop-access-point-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible.

I only know the method with **hostapd** to create an AP.

And to use *hostapd* with *rtl8188*, you **need** to use a patched version of *hostapd*. There are several version floating around. Look for rtl8188 and raspbian and hostapd in your *favorite search engine*.

For example [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=54946) or [here](https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd)

But extra step is needed to make the bridge to share internet connection.

To ease things, I recommend to use **create_ap** that will do it in one step. See https://github.com/oblique/create_ap

Answer (score 0):

you have to install new modules, then AP will works fine:

```
philipp@d3pi2:~ $ modinfo r8188eu
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.51-v7l+/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin
version:        v4.1.4_6773.20130222
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL

philipp@d3pi2:~ $ sudo su -
root@d3pi2:~/rtl_drw# mkdir rtl_drw; cd rtl_drw;  
root@d3pi2:~/rtl_drw# wget http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188eu-drivers/8188eu-5.4.51-v7l-1333.tar.gz
root@d3pi2:~/rtl_drw# tar -xzf 8188eu-5.4.51-v7l-1333.tar.gz
root@d3pi2:~/rtl_drw# ./install.sh
root@d3pi2:~/rtl_drw# reboot

philipp@d3pi2:~ $ modinfo 8188eu
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.51-v7l+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
version:        v5.3.9_28540.20180627
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL

philipp@d3pi2:~ $ sudo iwconfig wlan1
wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"PUTIN_KHUILO"  Nickname:"putinkhuilo"
          Mode:Master  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 20:0D:C0:21:EC:E8
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```