# Hotspot ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking

I used connectify on Windows, now a days I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I can't install connectify and I don't want it also, If there would another alternative. I have tried so many time [This Article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323335/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-with-an-ubuntu-laptop-access-point-mode), but when I wrote sudo -i gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot, It's appeared nothing but a blank. And my other device can't find my creating hotspot.

Please anyone can fix the problem.