# Transferring data between Ubuntu laptop and android device through Wi-Fie

Tags: file-sharing

Is it possible to transfer files from android to Ubuntu and vice versa
through Wi-Fi without using router and consuming internet bandwidth, in other words transferring data just like [zpya](http://www.izapya.com/) does.

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/254653/make-laptop-files-accessible-to-android-device-over-laptop-wifi-antenna it might be similar of what you ask.

Comment: Check AirDroid. Don't forget to use hotspot feature for more speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wifi hotspot on your android terminal. Connect your ubuntu system to it.

You can use Pushbullet to send files between them.

More information:

- [Pushbullet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android)
- [Pushbullet-indicator](http://m.webupd8.org/2015/03/pushbullet-indicator-gets-option-to.html?m=1)