# Recommended usb wifi adapter with hotsopt support

Tags: wireless, usb, hot-spot

i'd like to setup a wireless hotspot in ubuntu and would like to know what brands/models have master mode support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The [TL-WN722N](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N) is one of the least expensive dongle wifi cards that support master mode.

I have purchased one online before and paid $13 USD, including shipping.

There is a resource [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814057) where a user describes being able to achieve master mode using hostapd. A step by step tutorial on creating a wifi hotspot can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105217/how-do-i-create-a-non-adhoc-wifi-hotspot).

The signal won't be as strong as a wifi router, but for the price it's not bad.